# Batch renaming last few characters of files

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that would rename a bunch of files in a folder. These files would have a naming of something like: blah(lol).txt. There will always be a four letters, followed by an open bracket, three letters, and finally a close bracket.

I want the batch file to remove the bracketed part of the name of the file, ie. rename the file without the bracketed part.

```
    for %%i IN (*.txt) DO (set name=%%~ni
    set name2=%name:~1,4%
    ren %%i %name2%)
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3delims=()" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*(*).*" '
 ) DO ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%a(%%b)%%c" %%a%%b%%c

GOTO :EOF
```

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Answer (score 2):

Magoo provided an explanation as to why your script failed, as well as a working script.

But in your case, there is no need for a script. A simple REN command is all that is needed:

```
ren "????(???).txt" "????.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

simple but works from the folder with the files to be renamed.

```
@echo off
title Rename Bat
echo This bat must be in the folder that 
echo contains the files to be renamed.
:begin
echo Enter File Name
set /p old=
echo Enter New Name
set /p new=
ren "%old%" "%new%"
echo File Renamed
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 >NUL
goto begin
```

Answer (score -1):

a much simpler approach ... try a for loop that cycles through all files in your folder

I'm going to use lol as an example of three letter word inside brackets as stated in your question

@echo off

for %%a in (*) do (

rename "%%a" "%%a(lol).exe"

)

to use this batch file you have to place it in the folder containing the files you wanna rename

Comment: Yes, except they want to *remove* the bracketed part, not to add it. You are also missing the fact that `%%a` would be referencing the complete name, including the extension, and so `(lol).exe` in your script would not replace the original extension but rather be appended after it.